# Best way to store text from a website

Tags: html, css, web, server

Currently I am a beginner playing around with web development, and I am creating a website which involves a short text form to be filled out, and the next person who opens the website is able to view the text from the web form which was previously filled out.

I am wondering how about I would go about this. Do I need server side programming? If so, how would I implement things? I apologize if this is very obvious, I am new to the field.

Thank you.

edit: the front end html is very simple:

```
<head>
  <title>Tell me a secret.</title>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="prompt">
    <h1>TELL ME A SECRET</h1>
    <h3>
      <?php echo file_get_contents("secret.text"); ?>
    </h3>
    <form method="POST" action="save.php">
      <input type="text" id="secret" name="secret">
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

then you would need a save file:

```
<?php
  $secret = $_POST['secret'];
  $myfile = fopen("secret.txt", "w");
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myFile);
?>
```

Both of these will need to be `.php` files, and it will create / read the file in the same directory, called *secret.txt*.

**Warning:**  The key thing i want to inform you of, is the fact that anyone with access to that page will be able to write the contents, so be careful, as right now, anyone who can save this could inject html/javascript to do bad things to some peoples browsers..

Comment: Can you show us your mark up for the front end html, and maybe we could help you work on a server answer?   Also, do you know what server language you were planning to use?

Comment: I have update the post with the front end html. I have very little experience with server languages so I am open to anything.

Comment: If you have your webserver running, and PHP is available, I would say that is quick and simple.  Let me see what I can come up with

Comment: @Fallenreaper did you really just edit the question to contain your answer?

Comment: I messed up.  I didnt know how to revert it. >___>  I had it open in two tabs and accidentally did it in the wrong tab.  >______>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do, given your information.

Markup:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tell me a secret.</title>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="prompt">
    <h1>TELL ME A SECRET</h1>
    <h3>
      <?php echo file_get_contents("secret.text"); ?>
    </h3>
    <form method="POST" action="save.php">
      <input type="text" id="secret" name="secret">
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

then you would need a save file:

```
<?php
  $secret = $_POST['secret'];
  $myfile = fopen("secret.txt", "w");
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myFile);
?>
```

Both of these will need to be `.php` files, and it will create / read the file in the same directory, called *secret.txt*.

**Warning:**  The key thing i want to inform you of, is the fact that anyone with access to that page will be able to write the contents, so be careful, as right now, anyone who can save this could inject html/javascript to do bad things to some peoples browsers..